# Grouping values in separate Columns in R

Tags: r

I am new to R and I have the data in the following way 
these are the 2 columns

```
Broker_ID_Buy            Broker_ID_Sell

  638                       423
  546                       728
  423                       321
  546                       423
```

and it goes on there are around 28 different brokers appearing in buying or selling positions on different time

I need the data to be arranged like this

```
Broker_ID_638           Broker_ID_423         Broker_ID_546

BP                         SP                   IP
IP                         IP                   BP
IP                         BP                   IP
IP                         SP                   BP
```

Where BP= Buying Position, SP=Selling Position ,IP=Idle Position

I want to use these three different states for predicting using a Markov Chain

Comment: So, at the same time (one row in the first table) there can be only one buying and one selling broker, correct ?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to get you in the right ballpark:

```
library(reshape2)
x <- data.frame(BP = c(638,546,423,546), SP = c(423, 728, 321, 423))
x$index <- 1:nrow(x)
x.m <- melt(x, id.vars = "index")
out <- dcast(index ~ value, data = x.m, value.var="variable")
out[is.na(out)] <- "IP"
out
    #---
  index 321 423 546 638 728
1     1  IP  SP  IP  BP  IP
2     2  IP  IP  BP  IP  SP
3     3  SP  BP  IP  IP  IP
4     4  IP  SP  BP  IP  IP
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possible solution:

```
# create your table
txt <-
"Broker_ID_Buy,Broker_ID_Sell
638,423
546,728
423,321
546,423"
dt1 <- read.csv(text=txt)

# turn "Time, Broker_ID_Buy, Broker_ID_Sell" data.frame 
# into "Time, Broker_ID, Position"
buyers  <- data.frame(Time=1:nrow(dt1),
                      Broker_ID=dt1$Broker_ID_Buy,
                      Position="BP",
                      stringsAsFactors=F)
sellers <- data.frame(Time=1:nrow(dt1),
                      Broker_ID=dt1$Broker_ID_Sell,
                      Position="SP",
                      stringsAsFactors=F)           
longDT <- rbind(buyers,sellers)

# pivot the brocker ids on the columns 
wideDT <- reshape(data=longDT,direction="wide",
                  timevar="Broker_ID", idvar="Time", v.names="Position")

# well-format column names and turn NAs into "IP"
names(wideDT) <- sub(x=names(wideDT),pattern="Position.","Broker_ID_")
wideDT[is.na(wideDT)] <- "IP"
```

Result:

```
> wideDT
  Time Broker_ID_638 Broker_ID_546 Broker_ID_423 Broker_ID_728 Broker_ID_321
1    1            BP            IP            SP            IP            IP
2    2            IP            BP            IP            SP            IP
3    3            IP            IP            BP            IP            SP
4    4            IP            BP            SP            IP            IP
```